# Creating a heatmap without a colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, colorbar

I create 3 python plots with `colorbar()` from different data in separate folders using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as pp
pp.rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})

data=np.loadtxt("performance.dat")
A=np.reshape(data, (21,21,4))
x=A[:,:,0]
y=A[:,:,1]
rn=A[:,:,3]

f=pp.figure()
ax=f.add_subplot(111, )
fs=20
for tick in ax.axes.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
            tick.label.set_fontsize(fs)
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
            tick.label.set_fontsize(fs)

pp.pcolor(np.log10(x),np.log10(y),rn)
pp.clim(0,2)
pp.xlabel(r"$\log \, \sigma_1$", size=28)
pp.ylabel(r"$\log \, \sigma_2$",size=28)
pp.colorbar().ax.tick_params(labelsize=20) 
pp.show()
```

Then I insert it in my LaTeX file side by side with:

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\makebox[\linewidth][c]{
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth, bb = -0 -0 530 420]{m200_l10_p90}%-0 -0 588 444
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth, bb = -0 -0 530 420]{m200_l10_p95}%
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth, bb = -0 -0 530 420]{m200_l10_P99} 
\end{subfigure}
}
\caption{bla}
\label{fig:bla}
\end{figure}
```

I get:

[image: LaTeX output]

Clearly that does not look good, I played around LaTeX and until now that was the best I could get in order to make it readable. My idea was maybe to create only one plot showing the vertical color bar (the last plot), the first plot with only the "y label" and the middle one with the "x label", that would look better I think.

My question is how to create a colorbar plot without showing the bar? 
I tried to comment the `pp.colorbar().ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)` line but that messed up the plot.

The plots still need bigger label and ticks font size.

Comment: An alternative you could consider is PGFplots, which will create the plots directly in LaTeX. It contains built-in facilities for omitting axis labels when you have multiple plots that share an axis. But that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks @DavidZ, never heard of that. But i really would prefer a direct Python solution! Thanks for the edit too

Comment: Also, I tried creating a plot of this type without the `colorbar` call and it works fine. Could you elaborate on what goes wrong when you try removing that line?

Comment: following @DavidZ suggestion; why cant you just remove `pp.xlabel(r"$\log \, \sigma_1$", size=28)` for the first and third plot, `pp.ylabel(r"$\log \, \sigma_2$",size=28)` for the second and third plot and `pp.colorbar().ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)` for the first and second plot? you say it messes up the plot but do you mean that the dimensions of the plot are different from the other plots? In that case you could set explicitely set the figure sizes using `pp.figure(figsize=(width,height))`

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's the dimensions! then only the last one with the color bar stays square, the others become rectangles!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your data from different directories with `genfromtxt` by giving the path to `genfromtxt`:

```
np.genfromtxt('/path/to/performance.dat')
```

You can created all 3 heatmaps in one figure, using subplots.

Then, just add a new axes to the right, and plot the `colorbar` on that `axes` there (using the `cax` kwarg).

Finally, its easy to only add the `ylabel` to the left hand plot (only put it on `ax1`).

I've used `subplots_adjust` to set the margins in sensible places, and make room on the right for the colorbar. You'll notice that the bottom and top of the `subplots_adjust` command are reused to make the colorbar axis, so it all lines up nicely.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Sample data. You can get yours with np.genfromtxt('/path/to/performance.dat')
data1 = np.random.rand(20,20)*2
data2 = np.random.rand(20,20)*2
data3 = np.random.rand(20,20)*2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,3))

bottom,top,left,right = 0.2,0.9,0.1,0.85
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=bottom,left=left,right=right,top=top)

# fancy new colormap, just because...
plt.viridis()

# Add the 3 subplots
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(133)

# Plot the data
for ax,data in zip(fig.axes,[data1,data2,data3]):
    p=ax.pcolor(data,vmin=0,vmax=2)
    # xlabel on all subplots
    ax.set_xlabel(r"$\log \, \sigma_1$", size=28)

# ylabel only on the left
ax1.set_ylabel(r"$\log \, \sigma_2$", size=28)

# add_axes takes (left,bottom,width,height)
# height is just top-bottom
cax = fig.add_axes([right+0.05,bottom,0.03,top-bottom])
fig.colorbar(p,cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

An alternative way to line up all your subplots is to use `AxesGrid`, from `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1`, which will do that all automatically. Here's the script from above modified for `AxesGrid`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid

# Sample data. You can get yours with np.genfromtxt('/path/to/performance.dat')
data1 = np.random.rand(20,20)*2
data2 = np.random.rand(20,20)*2
data3 = np.random.rand(20,20)*2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,3))

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.viridis()

grid = AxesGrid(fig, 111,
                nrows_ncols=(1, 3),
                axes_pad=0.2,
                share_all=True,
                label_mode="L",
                cbar_location="right",
                cbar_mode="single",
                )

for ax,data in zip(grid,[data1,data2,data3]):
    p=ax.pcolor(data,vmin=0,vmax=2)
    ax.set_xlabel(r"$\log \, \sigma_1$", size=28)

grid[0].set_ylabel(r"$\log \, \sigma_2$", size=28)

grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(p)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Getting them from different paths is a good idea, I did not know that one!

Comment: Yeah, this would have been my suggestion as well (I just didn't get to write it up into an answer).